# Need help rendering item as complete in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple React app with goals and want to be able to mark them off as complete but am having trouble with setting complete to true once I click on the complete button. Here's my code:
I'm currently able to add and delete the goals, but complete is staying as false.

App.jsx:

```
 const [goals, setGoals] = useState([]);
  const [goal, setGoal] = useState({
    complete: false
  })

  function addGoal(newGoal) {
    setGoals((prevGoals) => {
      return [...prevGoals, newGoal];
    });
  }

  function deleteGoal(id) {
    setGoals((prevGoals) => {
      return prevGoals.filter((goalItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

 function completeGoal(id) {
    setGoals(
      goals.map(goal => {
        if (goal.id === id) {
          return {
complete: !goal.complete
          }
        }
        return goal;
      })
    )
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateGoal onAdd={addGoal} />
      {goals.map((goalItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Goal
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={goalItem.title}
            content={goalItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteGoal}
            onComplete={completeGoal}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is after the goal is added and displayed with the buttons for completing and deleting.

Goal.jsx:

```
function Goal(props) {

  function handleClick() {
    props.onDelete(props.id);
  }

  function handleGoal() {
    props.onComplete(props.id);
  }


 return (
 <div className="note">
   <h1>{props.title}</h1>
   <p>{props.content}</p>
   {/* <button className="fas fa-check"></button> */}
   <button onClick={handleGoal} className="complete-btn">
     <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
   </button>

   <button onClick={handleClick}>
     <i className="far fa-trash-alt">
       </i></button>
 </div>
 )
}

export default Goal
```

Comment: how does data in state `goals` look like? Also where are you using the state `goal`?

Answer (score 0):

Update your completeGoal function as below to set complete true

```
function completeGoal(id) {
setGoals((prev) =>
    prev.mapmap((goal) => (goal.id === id ? { ...goal, complete: true } : { ...goal })),
);
}
```